# Timezone from latitude and longitude in stata

Tags: geolocation, stata

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates) informative question but the answers address only implementations using programing languages I am not familiar with.

Does there exist a prewritten script from SSC or similar to get the timezone from lon and lat coordinates in stata?

EDIT:
I see. Thank you for the answer and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: `search` in Stata and Google are much better engines for searching. Otherwise we could have thousands of questions like this, all genuine individually but collectively inefficient and difficult to maintain. Downvoting for lack of research effort.

Comment: doubling down on downvoting!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very handy tool called google. It's amazing! you can find all sorts of things!

http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/graphics/spmap-and-maps/